# I want to make datagrid readonly in behnd code, but do not see the option

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, datagrid

I have a datagrid "AWGrid" which has EditCommandColumn and delete Templatecolumn.

When page loads I am checking for user privileges, if user does not have proper roles, it should just be able to view the content and edit and delete buttons should be disabled. Currently I am disabling those buttons on every event when they are clicked.

```
if (!wrp.PageAuthenticationForUser(currPage))
 {
    e.Item.Cells[0].Enabled = false;
     return;
 }
```

I want to disable those button on page load itself. Something like this

```
if (!wrp.PageAuthenticationForUser(currPage))
            {
                txtLbl.Text = "You are Not Authorized to do perform operation setup.";
                //AWGrid.ReadOny = true;
            }
```

But this does not seem to work. Is there a simple way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put your disabling button coding in gridview rowdatabound event.